# RACSignal catch to itself?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have an array of objects that represent some servers. All of them should answer to a certain web request. I need to query one of them (any one of them) and return a RACSignal for that, but if it fails I need to go to the next one in the list. Is it ok if I make a signal that gets one of them from the array tries to make the request , and if this fails catches to itself to try with another one from that list?

Answer (score 0):

Check my test example. I hope it helps you.

```
    RACSignal *signal1 = [RACSignal error:nil];
    RACSignal *signal2 = [RACSignal error:nil];
    RACSignal *signal3 = [RACSignal error:nil];
    RACSignal *signal4 = [RACSignal return:@5];

    NSArray<RACSignal *> *signals = @[signal1,
                                      signal2,
                                      signal3,
                                      signal4];

    NSMutableArray<RACSignal *> *catchedSignals = [NSMutableArray array];

    [signals enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(RACSignal * _Nonnull signal, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        RACSignal *catchedSignal = signal;
        if (idx != signals.count-1) {
            catchedSignal = [signal catchTo:catchedSignals.firstObject];
        }
        [catchedSignals insertObject:catchedSignal atIndex:0];
    }];

    [catchedSignals.firstObject subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        //print 5
        NSLog(@"x = %@", x);
    }];
```